# Different behavior using JOIN ON and JOIN ON WHERE

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables as shown **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15203/20).**

I am trying to fetch `name` and `register` variable WHEN `register` variable doesn't hold value present.

Using below query what I get is shown **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15203/18).**

```
SELECT t2.name, t1.register, t1.mydate 
FROM time t1
RIGHT JOIN user t2
ON t2.user_id=t1.user_id
WHERE (t1.register = 'absent' OR t1.register is null)
```

When I use below query I get INCORRECT result as shown **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15203/19).**

```
SELECT t2.name, t1.register, t1.mydate 
FROM time t1
RIGHT JOIN user t2
ON t2.user_id=t1.user_id AND (t1.register = 'absent' OR t1.register is null)
```

My question is: Why I am getting different result in above cases. I am using WHERE condition in ON clause itself so that I don't need to write WHERE condition.

Can someone point me in right direction?

Comment: The queries are the same but look at the sqlfiddle :p

Comment: the queries look the same to me

Comment: @iedoc, they were. I updated them from the fiddle.

Comment: thanks @Ben for editing sqlfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you put the `"t1.register = 'absent' OR t1.register is null"` condition in the WHERE clause, it applies after the join, whereas if you put it in the ON clause, it impacts the join.

It is absolutely normal and desired behavior :)

Here you have to put it in the WHERE clause :)

Answer (score 1):

I typically won't use right-join, but instead left-join... I know they are virtually the same, just which table from the join you want records from.  As Olivier mentioned, the WHERE clause is applied AFTER the join condition.  I would typically start by asking what do I want... In your case, I want ALL users listed REGARDLESS of a registration time... so, I would simply put it as

```
select
      u.Name,
      t.register,
      t.myDate
   from
      users u
         LEFT JOIN time t
            on u.user_id = t.user_id
```

My left table (always want) is users... time is right-side table, and I always try to keep my "ON" join condition representing the left/right correlation for readability.

Now, this is not exactly what you want, but its where I start...  Now, how to apply the "absent" status.  Since the above already gets all users, and you only want to see the entries where "absent" occurs, add that to the JOIN portion because those are the only entries you are interested in seeing.

```
select
      u.Name,
      t.register,
      t.myDate
   from
      users u
         LEFT JOIN time t
            on u.user_id = t.user_id
          AND t.register = 'absent'
```

So, only the records with "absent" will show their respective register and mydate values... any other record, you'll still get every person.  No WHERE clause is required.

However, if say you only wanted users who were a certain type or status, you could add that to restrict those "users" you wanted to see... such as

```
select
      u.Name,
      t.register,
      t.myDate
   from
      users u
         LEFT JOIN time t
            on u.user_id = t.user_id
          AND t.register = 'absent'
   where
      u.SomeStatus = whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to the order of execution of your query.
The normal order is

```
 From
 JOIN
 WHERE
 SELECT
```

So, in the first example

```
SELECT t2.name, t1.register, t1.mydate 
FROM time t1
RIGHT JOIN user t2
ON t2.user_id=t1.user_id
WHERE (t1.register = 'absent' OR t1.register is null)
```

First, the two table will join together (using inner join) based on the condition `t2.user_id=t1.user_id`, and then all no-matched rows from the **time** table will be added to the temporary result table. Finally, the conditions in the WHERE clause `(t1.register = 'absent' OR t1.register is null)` are applied to the temporary table to produce the final result.

In the second example

```
SELECT t2.name, t1.register, t1.mydate 
FROM time t1
RIGHT JOIN user t2
ON t2.user_id=t1.user_id AND (t1.register = 'absent' OR t1.register is null)
```

First, the two tables join together (using inner join) based on the conditions `t2.user_id=t1.user_id AND (t1.register = 'absent' OR t1.register is null)`. Next, all no-matched rows from **time** are added to the result.

For all of that, the results the two queries are different.

If you use **INNER JOIN**, then the conditions on WHERE or ON clauses produce the same result. They are only different if you use **OUTER JOINs ( LEFT/ RIGHT/ CROSS)**.